# Outlook Web Addin is running Internet Explorer and not Web View 2

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We have an Web Addin on Outlook that need modern browser like Edge Chromium.

So in order to change the old IE as a browser Engine inside Outlook to render our web addins, we did:

1. Update Windows;
2. Update Office 365 Desktop App;
3. Install Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime;

But the addin still runing in IE. Any Ideia? The other PCs, i did this 3 steps and it works, but i have 2 computers with this problem. There is the versions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you happen to solve this issue? It's incredible how the MS staff don't get here to help and reply to people!!

Comment: I have a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558304/how-to-force-microsoft-office-addin-to-use-edge-webview2-runtime

Comment: This question is not on topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on Stack Overflow must be directly related to programming. This question may work better on [su].

Comment: The questioner is trying to set up the right browser environment for an outlook add-in (e.g. a javascript/html application that runs inside of outlook). This seems analogous to a node developer running into an issue configuring which version of node should run - pretty relevant to programming.